# Selecting data from different ts dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, time-series, dataframe

Basically, I just want to be able to "bring" data to df2 from another df1, using as a selection criteria the index of df2 + some days.

df1

```
               Open     High      Low    Close
2005-09-07  1234.50  1238.00  1231.25  1237.00
2005-09-08  1235.00  1242.75  1231.75  1238.75
2005-09-09  1237.50  1250.25  1237.50  1247.75
2005-09-12  1248.75  1251.00  1245.25  1247.00
2005-09-13  1245.25  1246.75  1237.50  1238.00
```

df2

```
                Ref     
2005-09-07        1  
2005-09-08        2  
2005-09-09        3
```

Desired Output = Df2

```
              Ref   1d.Close 2d.Close 3d.Close
2005-09-07      1    1238.75  1247.75  1247.00
2005-09-08      2    1247.75  1247.00  1238.00
2005-09-09      3    1247.00  1238.00      NaN
```

This is what I have tried (please don't laugh):

```
df2['date.value'] = df2.index  
df2['+1d.Date'] = df2['date.value'] + timedelta(1)
df2['1d.Close'] = df1['Close'].loc[df2['date.value']]
```

This approach gives me NaN, but if I use:

```
df2['1d.Close'] = df1['Close'].loc[df2['2005-09-07']]
```

This would give me 1238.75 which would be correct for the first row of the example.
But for some reason It doesn't work in the formula.

Final Notes:

- The dates on df2 are not always consecutive
- The "length" of the timedelta is variable too and not always consecutive.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried pd.merge()?

Comment: @Inox I have not. Now I will try. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is to create 3 new dataframes (if it is always 1, 2 and 3 days you want to shift). Each one would be exactly df1, just with the index shifted by 1, 2 and 3 days.

```
df_1 = df
df_1.index = df_1.index + 1 #not sure if that is the right calculation
```

Repeat for df_2 and df_3 (with +2 and +3)

Then I would rename the columns of each dataframe, and delete useless columns

```
del df_1['Open']
del df_1['High']
del df_1['Low']
df_1.columns = ['d1Close']
```

Again repeat for df_2 and df_3.

Then just merge:

```
Df2 = pd.merge(df2,df_1,how =  'left', left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

and repeat for df_2 and df_3 (but for those, use pd.merge(Df2,...).

This merge means a left join (you'll keep all values from df2, regardless if there's a match or not in the df_1 table), you're merging on the index (using index as key)

I guess not all of that will work perfectly, but that's the idea

Comment: Your idea wasn't very specific of accurate, but it covered the gist of what you have to do. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. As I said, not all of that will work perfectly, but that's the idea